# Awk use shell variable inside begin block

Tags: bash, awk

Below is a file named sites.txt:

```
google is good
yahoo is dying
microsoft is ok
faceBook is vulnerable
```

Script::

```
#!/bin/bash

site="facebook"

awk -v s="$site" 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1} /s/' sites.txt
```

But the above command does not return any output. How can I use a shell variable inside the begin block to display correct output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

Comment: You're not trying to use a shell variable inside a BEGIN block, you're trying to use it inside a regular expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command is literally matching `s` in every line.

You should be using `~` operator:

```
awk -v s="$site" 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1} $0 ~ s' sites.txt
```

Note that `IGNORECASE = 1` is a gnu awk feature and if you want a POSIX compliant way then use:

```
awk -v s="$site" 'tolower($0) ~ tolower(s)' sites.txt
```